# Redux + React-Navigation: TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

I'm not able to debug this error. I am integrating react-navigation's Stack Navigator with Redux and have trouble initializing the Store. I have a very simple structure. Thanks in advance

Registered component:

```
    const App = () => {    
      return (
        <Provider store={createStore(reducers)}>
          <AppWithNavigationState />
        </Provider>
      );
    };
```

Redux connected Component:

```
class AppWithNavigationState extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log('rendered AppWithNavigationState');

    return (
      <TopLevelRouter
        navigation={addNavigationHelpers({
          dispatch: this.props.dispatch,
          state: this.props.nav
        })}
      />
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { nav: state.nav };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AppWithNavigationState);
```

StackNavigator:

```
const Routes = {
  Profile: { screen: ProfileScreen },
};

export const TopLevelRouter = StackNavigator(Routes);
```

and reducers:

```
export default combineReducers({
  nav: NavigationReducer,
  loggedIn: AuthReducer
});
```

and

```
const initialState = TopLevelRouter.router.getStateForAction(
  TopLevelRouter.router.getActionForPathAndParams('Profile'));


export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  const newState = TopLevelRouter.router.getStateForAction(state, action);
  return newState || state;
};
```

Full stack trace:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined

This error is located at:
    in App (at renderApplication.js:35)
    in RCTView (at View.js:71)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:102)
    in RCTView (at View.js:71)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:122)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:34)
Object.getStateForAction
\src\routers\StackRouter.js:158:40
exports.default
\src\reducers\NavigationReducer.js:19:41
<unknown>
\node_modules\redux\lib\combineReducers.js:53:23
assertReducerShape
\node_modules\redux\lib\combineReducers.js:51:24
combineReducers
\node_modules\redux\lib\combineReducers.js:107:4
<unknown>
\src\reducers\index.js:5:31
loadModuleImplementation
\node_modules\metro\src\lib\polyfills\require.js:213:4
guardedLoadModule
\node_modules\metro\src\lib\polyfills\require.js:147:11
_require
\node_modules\metro\src\lib\polyfills\require.js:131:2
```

Comment: Can you console.log the TopLevelRouter import to ensure you are importing it correctly? You don't set it to `default` when exporting.

Comment: thanks Travis, i'm using `import { TopLevelRouter }` . My console log in the `NavigationReducer` file says TopLevelRouter is the following function:

` NavigationContainer(props) {
        _classCallCheck(this, NavigationContainer);

        var _this = _possibleConstructorReturn(this, (NavigationContainer.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(Navigati…`

Comment: What about console.log(TopLevelRouter.router)? If it isn't undefined then I'm not sure what is causing the undefined of undefined error. Something not imported or setup properly somewhere :-\

Comment: What line is at renderApplication.js:35?

Comment: to your first comment, seems to work fine, returns an object of functions:
{getComponentForState: ƒ, getComponentForRouteName: ƒ, getStateForAction: ƒ, getPathAndParamsForState: ƒ, getActionForPathAndParams: ƒ, …}

Comment: To your second comment, it is the Root Component call in:
let renderable = (
    <AppContainer rootTag={rootTag} WrapperComponent=`{WrapperComponent}>
      <RootComponent {...initialProps} rootTag={rootTag} />
    </AppContainer>
  );

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163829/discussion-between-nth-gol-and-travis-white).

Answer (score 0):

React Navigation's redux integration is quickly changing as of late Jan 2018. It now has event listener requirements, see the github examples.

I wasn't able to pinpoint the exact error but I had success starting from scratch and following this guide: https://medium.com/async-la/a-stately-guide-to-react-navigation-with-redux-1f90c872f96e

Just note that you will have to add a listener to the root navigation router, which isn't covered in the guide